# Find a subspace $S$ of $V$ such that $V=W\oplus S.$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

Let $V$ be the space of all real-valued maps on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $W$ be the subset of $V$ consisting of maps $f$ such that $f(0)+f(1)=0.$

a) Check that W is a subspace of V.

b) Find a subspace S of V such that $V=W\oplus S$.

I checked that $W$ is a subspace, but I am having trouble in finding it's complement $S$. My first idea was to consider functions $g$ such that $g(1)+g(0)\not =0$, but then I realized that the space of these functions will not be a vector space since it does not contain the $0$ function. Any hints/ideas for part $(b)$ would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth thinking about dimension here. Note that the map $\phi : V \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(f) = f(0) + f(1)$ is linear, and the kernel is $W$. It follows therefore that $W$ has co-dimension $1$, basically saying that $S$ must be dimension $1$.

How do we find a suitable $1$-dimensional $S$? It's pretty simple. We should be able to choose the span of almost any element: just so long as it doesn't lie in $W$. For example, $f(x) \equiv 1$ works, and $\operatorname{span} \lbrace f \rbrace$ is a suitable choice for $S$.

Comment: What do you mean by by co-dimension?

Comment: It actually just means exactly what I said next: a subspaces $W$ has codimension $n$ there's a $n$-dimensional subspace $S$ you can direct sum to $W$ to get $V$.

Comment: By the rank-nullity theorem, we can say that $\dim \text{Image}(\phi)+\dim W=\dim V.$ I am guessing that $\dim \text{Image}(\phi)=\dim \mathbb{R}=1$ and so we need a space $S$ such that $\dim S=\dim \mathbb{R}=1$, right? Is that how you are reasoning?

Comment: That's exactly the intuition, yes. However, in this case, we have an infinite-dimensional $V$. So, rather than having to deal with $\operatorname{dim} V = \operatorname{dim} W = \infty$, we have a notion of codimension: measuring the number of dimensions missing, not the number of dimensions present.

Comment: Well, this idea is illuminating! Thank you for your answer.